calling 0x price api endpoint and getting error 400 Bad request
I have a simple front end, and when the user inputs an amount , on blur i want to show the amount of token B they will be buying with the input amount.
for that I'm trying to use 0x price api
const handleBlur = async () => {
        /**@DEV on blur will use the 0x api to fetch token price  */
        if(amount1 !== 0 && selectedToken1 !== "" && selectedToken2!== ""){
            
            const params = { 
                chainId:8453,
                buyToken: selectedToken2.address,
                sellToken:selectedToken1.address,
                sellAmount:amount1
            }
            const headers = {'0x-api-key': `${process.env.ZERO_X_API_KEY}`};
            const resp = await fetch(`https://api.0x.org/swap/permit2/price?${qs.stringify(params)}`,{headers});
            console.log(resp.json);
        }
    }

This is the function that handles the fetch request to the 0x API.
also here you can find the documentation of the API and its params
https://0x.org/docs/api

Instead of passing params as Object, you've to pass them individually as query parameters, which are part of the URL.
Also, you've to pass '0x-version': 'v2' in the headers.
Here's an example:
const chainId = 1;
const sellToken = '0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee';
const buyToken = '0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48';
const sellAmount = '1000000000000000000';
const apiKey = process.env.ZERO_X_API_KEY;

const url = `https://api.0x.org/swap/permit2/price?chainId=${chainId}&sellToken=${encodeURIComponent(sellToken)}&buyToken=${encodeURIComponent(buyToken)}&sellAmount=${sellAmount}`;

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        '0x-api-key': apiKey,
        '0x-version': 'v2'
    }
};

fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));


I had to modify that version a bit and got it running , thanks for the reply. I also noticed that CORS on Brave browser was blocking the fetch from the front end of the app, so I had to make the call on the client side.
